# Route::currentRouteAction not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I am trying to create a middleware that checks the method action for the current route.

My middleware is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Route;

class PermissionMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $currentAction = Route::currentRouteAction();

    list($nothing,$route_action) = explode('App\Http\Controllers\\', $currentAction);

    $user_methods=session('userdata')['route_actions'];

    if((empty($user_methods))||!$user_methods->contains($route_action))
    {
        return redirect('denied');
    }
    return $next($request);

 }
}
```

But when I go to the route, it throws up an error as shown below

[image]

indicating

> Undefined offset: 1
>   in PermissionMiddleware.php (line 21)

I cant figure out how to resolve the error.

I would need a guide to figure this out

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your problem is not `Route::currentRouteAction()` but after the following line:

```
list($nothing, $route_action) = explode('App\Http\Controllers\\', $currentAction);
```

It's not very obvious where it's happening but you should check the the following line:

```
$user_methods = session('userdata')['route_actions'];
```

Make sure that, `session('userdata')` returns the expected result for example:

```
if ($userData = session('userdata')) {

    if (isset($userData['route_actions'])) {

        $user_methods = $userData['route_actions'];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also, you can use `$request->route()->getActionName()` to get the same result instead of using `Route::currentRouteAction()`. There are other useful methods available to get information about the route action for example:

```
$request->route()->getActionMethod(); // get the method name

$request->route()->getAction(); // get an array containing many information
```

Comment: Thank you @The Alpha for your guidance. However, it seems route() is not available in Middleware because when I try the examples you gave, it returns an error that indicates that I am calling the getActionMethod on null.

Call to a member function getActionName() on null

Comment: You should be able to use `$request->route()->getActionMethod()` or `$request->route()->getAction()`.